# how to define data structure of D3 to draw pie ring

Tags: d3.js, data-structures, data-visualization

I am a D3 newer and wrote a program to draw a pie ring.

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>pie ring</title>  
</head> 

<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataset=[{name:A,value:5},{name:C,value:10},{name:F,value:13}];
        var pie=d3.layout.pie(dataset);

        var h=600;
        var w=600;

        var outerRadius=w/2;

        var innerRadius=w/3;

        var arc=d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius);

        var svg=d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width",w)
                .attr("height",h);

        var color=d3.scale.category10();

        var arcs=svg.selectAll("g.arc")
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","arc")

        .attr("transform","translate("+outerRadius+","+outerRadius+")");//translate(a,b)


        arcs.append("path")
        .attr("fill",function(d,i){
            return color(i);
        })
        .attr("d",arc);


        arcs.append("text")
        .attr("transform",function(d){ 
            return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .text(function(d){
            return d.name + ":" + d.value;
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But failed, I don't know that how to define data structure and don't know how to pie dataset. pie(dataset) or pie(function(d){return d.value} );         could you help me to correct it

the javascript console told me that A is not defined. This A is the value of the name of the dataset.  I don't know if the only request is digital value or digital array for pie ring.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain *how* it failed, instead of simply reiterating the fact that something somehow went wrong (why else would you be here?). Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here. It's telling you A isn't defined because it's not. You're using plain text instead of a string, so it thinks A is a variable, not a label. Even if you resolved that, there would be some other issues with the structure.

Copied almost straight from the d3 pie chart example [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch11.html#_pie_layout), I put in your data and it works a charm.

[image]

Here's the code, but I also strongly recommend going over the tutorial so you can see how it's supposed to work.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>pie ring</title>  
</head> 

<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 600;                        
    var h = 600;    

    var outerRadius=w/2;
    var innerRadius=w/3;


    color = d3.scale.category20c();    

    data = [{"label":"A", "value":5}, 
            {"label":"C", "value":10}, 
            {"label":"F", "value":13}];

    var vis = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg:svg")           
        .data([data])                 
            .attr("width", w)          
            .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")               
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")  

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()              
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()          
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });    

    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")    
        .data(pie)                         
        .enter()                           
            .append("svg:g")              
                .attr("class", "slice");  

        arcs.append("svg:path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) 
                .attr("d", arc);                                   

        arcs.append("svg:text")                                  
                .attr("transform", function(d) {                 
                d.innerRadius = innerRadius;
                d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";       
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")                        
            .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].label; });  

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```